# Accessing remote redis server with Grafana

Tags: docker, redis, grafana

I'm trying to access my redis database via Grafana Cloud on my laptop. The database is a redis container working as a cache on a different device (pi). Accessing the Redis database via Python script on my remote device is no problem but trying to connect to it via Grafana (using Redis Datasource Plugin) doesn't work as intended and throws a connection error. Poorly the documentation leaves me kinda clueless whats the specific cause (any missing plugin dependencies?) so I'm thankful for every hint.

[image]

Comment: Is redis exposed on the public ip?

Comment: Ahh this could be the issue. If I run Grafana as docker container on the same device as my database could I access and control Grafana via remote_ip:grafana_port from my browser on a different device like for example portainer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to access Redis Server from Grafana Cloud it should be exposed to the Internet as Jan mentioned.

If you run Grafana in Docker container it should be started in the host network mode (https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) to be able to access it from other devices.

If something is lacking or not clear in the Redis plugins documentation, please open an issue and we will update it: https://github.com/RedisGrafana/RedisGrafana/issues